# How to set the MirrorType/Stretch options of a slide background in PowerPoint

Tags: delphi, powerpoint, office-interop

I can get the background image exported, however, when I set the background to tiled the "Mirror Type" option is set to "Both" by default. I want to set this to "None" and I want to be able to set some of the Offsets in the Stetch options.

I have imported the 2010 Type Library into Delphi but I can't seem to find these options anywhere. I also tried messing about with Macros in 2010 but still couldn't seem to see it. I tried some options which I thought were the strecth options e.g. Left/IncrementLeft etc but I just kept getting exceptions like:

*"ShapeRange (unknown member): Invalid Request. This operation can't be applied to a background shape."*

Here is what I am doing at the moment:

```
    Slide.Background.Fill.UserPicture('C:\Path\To\Image.jpg')
    if DoTile Then
    begin
        Slide.Background.Fill.TextureTile := msoTrue
        // need to set Mirror type to none
    end
    else
        // need to change some of the stretch offsets
```

Comment: This functionality appears not to be available via the PowerPoint object model.

Comment: @David - that was my worry! It's quite frustrating as when you set a background image to tiled through the UI the Mirror type by default is None, doing it via the API seems to set it to Both (not sure if it's maybe the order in which I am doing it).